# Invalid drawable tag vector

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Im trying to use vector drawables on pre lollipop devices. I did all as instructed [here](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.1n8w97x4a) but i still get this crash.

***build.gradle:***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://maven.android-forever.com' }
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile "de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0"
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
    compile "com.af:android-utility:1.0.0.9"
    compile project(':volleyplus')
    compile project (':libvlc')
}
```

triangle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/triangle_v"/>
</selector>
```

*triangle_v.xml*

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

<path
    android:name="triangle"
    android:fillColor="#FF0000"
    android:pathData="m 50,0 l 50,100 -100,0 z"/>

</vector>
```

*layout.xml*

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/triangle"/>
```

I also tried `app:srcCompat` and in that case, drawable just dont show.

Comment: I've noticed that using vectors within a `selector` and as a layout background results in these exceptions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was that my activity wasn't extending `AppCompatActivity` but regular `Activity`.

This is not specified in any documentation/example for support vector drawables

Answer (score 35):

Got this problem too when loading vectors from a selector on pre-lollipop devices:

Use **AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)** in your onCreate method:

> Sets whether vector drawables on older platforms (< API 21) can be
>   used within android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer resources.
>   When enabled, AppCompat can intercept some drawable inflation from the
>   framework, which enables implicit inflation of vector drawables within
>   android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer resources.

```
protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ...
```

Comment: I faced the question's problem even if I have 'app:srcCompat'. But this answer fix my issue.

Comment: This fixed my worries

Comment: This did not fix it for me.

Comment: did not fix the problem for me , getting this only on versions < 21

Answer (score 33):

This code is going to work with vector if using
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

And change `android:src` to `app:srcCompat`.

For example,

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:src="@drawable/triangle"/>
> ```

to

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:srcCompat="@drawable/triangle"/>
> ```

Comment: This answer helped me.  Edited for clarity.  Original author deserved better than two down votes.

Comment: This is the real answer! It shouldn't be the other one unless you really forgot to extend AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 27):

I faced a similar problem and @pedja's own answer is useful.
More generally, as mentioned in [Chris Banes's article on vector drawable compat](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.599tldn2m), the support library works by injecting its version of `ImageView` over the system one on pre-L via some hooks.  This implicitly requires the AppCompat versions of classes, such as `AppCompatActivity`, be used.

In my case, the vector drawable is used in a standalone toast-like view without an associated activity, using the Application context.  I ended up using `AppCompatImageView` in the xml layout definition directly, i.e. something like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
             android:id="@+id/some_id"
             android:layout_width="24dp"
             android:layout_height="24dp"
             android:src="@drawable/selector_referencing_vector_drawable"/>
```

thus there is no need for the magic "hook" mechanism.  As tested this also works with the `Activity` class without the need of using `AppCompatActivity`.  All the above was done without upgrading to 23.2.1, which addressed a different problem.

Comment: No, you should use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` in order to have pre-Lollipop vector drawables working.

Comment: <cough> is it just me or did the Googlers neglect to provide an app-compat solution for TextView drawables? (e.g. `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/somevector"`)</cough>

Comment: I solved the **drawableLeft** problem adding `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in the `onCreate(...)` method and then setting the drawable programmatically via `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(<drawable_id>), null, null, null)`

Answer (score 14):

The answers given here are ignoring a situation when you wish to add a drawable to a textview because it gives the same error. in my case I had

```
<TextView .... android:drawableLeft="some_vectore_drawable" />
```

I could not find how to solve this so I removed that line from the xml code and put it in my java code in this manner

```
Drawable somevectordrable = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, R.drawable.somevectordrawable);
mytextview.setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds(somevectordrable, null, null, null);
```

Clarification for the code,

1. Get the vector drawable from the drawables folder using AppCompatDrawableManager
2. Set the drawable we just got as the left drawable on our textview

Comment: This worked for me. I upgraded to Gradle 3 and then started seeing crashes on all 4.n devices. What did it was using:  `AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(this, R.drawable.arrow);` instead of `ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.arrow);` for all pre-lollipop devices.

Comment: It gives warning **AppCompatDrawableManager** can only be called from within the same library group

Comment: @Nainal maybe something in the code from google has changed, it did not give me a warning when I did it which was last year at around the time this answer was posted

Comment: @Albert Vila Calvo has an answer for how to do this in xml itself

Answer (score 8):

That's all I fond over the internet, and it's work for me. Check which one you miss.

1) Inside **build.gradle**

```
 android {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
  }
```

2) Must use  `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'` and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'` similar version code.

3) Use upper then 3 gradle version
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`

4) For `ImageView` use `app:srcCompat`

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
```

5) But if you need `android:drawableLeft`or `android:drawableRigth` etc then:

> ic_logo.xml (Vector xml)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:width="@dimen/home.button.icon"
    android:height="@dimen/home.button.icon"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    tools:ignore="VectorRaster">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M9,16.17L4.83,12l-1.42,1.41L9,19 21,7l-1.41,-1.41z"/>
</vector>
```

> ic_logo_select.xml (Vector selector)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo" />
</selector>
```

> Now you can use **android:drawableLeft** or **android:drawableRight**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_logo_select"/>
```

6) And at the end, setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true inside static which loads before the main method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     static {
            AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I've struggled with drawableLeft and drawableTop, but your solution is the one which really works. Thank you!

Comment: This is great answer ... it should be ticked as answer ... it worked perfect. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Note that for `drawableLeft` and `drawableRight` you don't need the `<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo" />` item. Having only `<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo" />` is enough.

Answer (score 6):

You also need to include the new vector support library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0'
```

Comment: Nope, that libray is included implicitly by setting `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

Answer (score 6):

**It works with 23.2.0 or 23.4.0, not 23.3.0. Seriously Google!**

> First up, this functionality was originally released in 23.2.0, but
>   then we found some memory usage and Configuration updating issues so
>   we it removed in 23.3.0. In 23.4.0 (technically a fix release) we’ve
>   re-added the same functionality but behind a flag which you need to
>   manually enable.

Ref : https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.waicp19gh

Comment: this is the way to  go
AppCompatImageView with srcCompat

Answer (score 4):

If you have this exception issue with `drawableLeft`,`drawableRight`,`drawableTop`, `drawableXxx` etc... And your project `buildToolsVersion` > `26.0.2`.

Go check your app level gradle file, remove `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` if exists, then crash gone.

This because buildTools will dispose vector resource after 26.0.2, but somehow conflict with `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`.

Tested at 2019/03/27.

(if you can't find your `buildToolsVersion` in you app level gradle file, this mean you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies. In this case your `buildToolsVersion` already large than 26.0.2)

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised that this is not mentioned here yet.

This crash happens often with:

```
android:drawableRight
android:drawableLeft
android:drawableTop
android:drawableBottom
android:drawableStart
android:drawableEnd
```

A common fix is to create another drawable that wraps the drawable with `<selector><item android:drawable=""></selector>`, or to set the compound drawable using code, but nowadays you can instead use:

```
app:drawableRightCompat
app:drawableLeftCompat
app:drawableTopCompat
app:drawableBottomCompat
app:drawableStartCompat
app:drawableEndCompat
```

This was added to `AppCompatTextView` in [appcompat 1.1.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha01).

To use the attribute I've had to use AppCompat views instead of usual ones, eg. I've used `AppCompatButton` instead of `Button`.

---

Not sure if you need `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true` and `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` (I have both). Check this article from Nick Butcher: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-vector-assets-in-android-apps-4318fd662eb9.

Answer (score 1):

This is support-v4, appcompat-v7 library v23.2.0 bug it appears in API 19.
@tim provide link to this bug issue.

You can upgrade to new library version 23.2.1 and bug is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this issue with `drawableLeft`/`drawableStart`, etc. there is an easy solution, if you're using databinding.

Instead of:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/somevector" ❌
```

Do:

```
android:drawableLeft="@{@drawable/somevector}" ✅
```

This works because databinding will generate code at compile time that retrieves the drawable in a compatible way.

Comment: Calling `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` in the application was also required. But your solution worked perfeclty

Comment: This gives me a build error of "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@{@drawable/.....

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue on code.google.

It appears to be the same issue as you.
Does this help?
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201843

Answer (score 0):

If you see yourself using `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` when loading a vector drawable it might be a better idea to extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` and go back to using regular `<ImageView...app:srcCompat="@drawable/...`