# Drawable in EditText crashes Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-design-library

When I use a drawable icon in my edittext, my activity crashes. Without drawable everything is working fine. The strange thing is, this crashes on API Level 16, but not on API Level 26.

This is my Error log:

```
     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/login_password.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070068
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1998)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0: invalid drawable tag vector
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
```

This my EditText View. I'm using it with TextInputLayout

```
           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_inputlayout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_login_titel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/login_textEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login_password"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/login_password"
                android:hint="Email Adresse"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/global_edittext" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This [is another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361107/unable-to-use-drawable-in-edittext-inside-textinputlayout), but is outdated. I tried the solution and other answers, but nothing really works for me.

Comment: Your drawable is an SVG?

Comment: The drawable is a vector asset from the provided material icon set.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015208/3635454

Comment: @pleft thanks for the comment, but it did not help me solve the problem :(

Comment: @JulieNoobie Hey I am getting the same error, Did you find any fix for this. Can you please help me.

Comment: Hey, I did not find any fix yet. Sorry :(

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix the issue. Am stuck with the same issue since one day.

Answer (score 0):

API Levels less than 21 does not support `xml` drawables for `background` attribute. I have the same problem. You can use image for it. jpg, png or other formats like this.